Imprimir archivo .txt creado desde codigo ASP.NET CORE MVC
tengo un programa que crea un archivo txt y lo guarda en el disco de la pc, eso funciona bien y lo hago de la siguiente manera en el controlador:
string nombreArchivo = "Archivo.txt";
string ubicacion = @"C:\";
string archivo = System.IO.Path.Combine(ubicacion, nombreArchivo);
if (!System.IO.File.Exists(archivo))
{
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(archivo))
    {
        sw.WriteLine("Prueba");
    }
}

Ahora lo que quiero es que ese archivo pueda imprimirse con solo presionar el boton, pero no he logrado que funcione.
Intente con PrintDocument pero no funciona, me reconoce la impresora pero no imprime.
De esta manera lo uso en el mismo controlador donde cree el archivo:
PrintDocument pri = new PrintDocument();
PrinterSettings pr = new PrinterSettings();
pri.PrinterSettings = pr;
pri.DocumentName = nombreArchivo;
pri.Print();

Entonces, yo solo quiero que imprima el archivo recien creado.
Espero me puedan ayudar, muchas gracias de antemano.

No es tan simple, porque básicamente lo que se imprime es un dibujo (una imagen), entonces hay que calcular la posición de cada línea. Para esto, como mínimo, debes establecer una fuente con su tamaño, porque dependiendo de eso cambia el alto de la línea. Algo así:
private void Imprimir(string Ruta)
{

    StreamReader stream = new(Ruta);
    Font font = new("Arial", 10);
    PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
    pd.PrintPage += (sender, ev) => PrintPage(ev, font, stream);
    pd.Print();
}
private void PrintPage(PrintPageEventArgs ev, Font printFont, StreamReader sr )
{
    int count = 0;
    string line = null;

    // Calcula la cantidad de páginas
    float linesPerPage = ev.MarginBounds.Height / printFont.GetHeight(ev.Graphics);

    // Imprimte cada linea
    while (count < linesPerPage && (line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        float yPos = ev.MarginBounds.Top + (count * printFont.GetHeight(ev.Graphics));
        ev.Graphics.DrawString(line, printFont, Brushes.Black, ev.MarginBounds.Left, yPos, new StringFormat());
        count++;
    }

       
    if (line != null)
        ev.HasMorePages = true;
    else
        ev.HasMorePages = false;
}


Esto me funciono, muchas gracias!!!!
